# Hard Drive Problems

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have an old laptop (Core i3 with 4GB RAM) with Windows 10 and Windows 8.1, which took forever to boot.

That's why I installed Ubuntu 18.04. Eventually, I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. I have also upgraded my RAM to 12gb.

I also decided that I won't need Windows anymore, so I deleted all the folders that (I think) were associated with Windows, so I can use the disk space for my Linux files.

There were some apps which could open/create files on these ex-Windows drives. There are others who won't. And I have no idea why.

Also when I looked at KDE Partition Manager (Please see picture below), I noticed two (2) things:

1. There is an unmounted drive (`/dev/sda4` `fat16`) that is 499MB in size, with 0B used.
2. There is another drive (`/dev/sda6` `ext4`) that is about 54GB in size, with 37.75GB used

[image: My KDE Screen Shot]

My questions are:

1. What are these drives?
2. How can I tell Ubuntu 20.04 to use my ex-windows drives in saving files?

Comment: Have you updated UEFI? Some systems only update from Windows. Most have ways to just use an update file in FAT32 partition and read that directly from UEFI? Your sda2 is required by Windows. And all NTFS partitions will be Windows. You can create a new ext4 partition and move /home to it. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving
 Or add data partitions.

Comment: Thank you for this Link!!! I have a ne HOME directory now... THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: Your /home has to be a Linux format like ext4. You can use NTFS for data, but do not use NTFS unless also keeping Windows or at least a Windows repair disk as you cannot do essential NTFS maintenance from Linux like chkdsk & defrag.

Answer (score 1):

/dev/sda4 is probably a Windows boot partition, /dev/sda6 is the system partition of Ubuntu, aka the root partition.

To use the two old Windows partitions, you need to mount them properly. Usually, it's done automatically when the user clicks it in the file browser, and the mount point is of the following kind, /media/user-name/mount-point. 
As seen in the screenshot, they are mounted under /mnt which isn't ideal from the usability point of view.

Comment: yes, /dev/sda4 is a windows partition. I just don't know if it's a windows boot partition. Now I can't do anything with that partition. I ca' format, mount or do anything with it. I absolutely need help here.

Also, how can I make the other two drives in the "/mnt" usable to other apps, like android studio or flowblade? These apps can't read files from these drives.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, I don't know what's the problem exactly. Why can't you do anything, what happens when you try, and what errors do you get? Also, who set up those mount points in `/mnt`? You need to unmount a partition first, then should be able to format it, for example `sudo umount /dev/sda3`.

Comment: Wait. Let me do it again and I'll take a screenshot. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Well, what do you know. When I checked my FIle Manager, /dev/sda4 is now mounted! I have no idea what happened! Hahahaha.

At any rate, I still have 1 more problem. how can my make /dev/sda3, /dev/sda4,  and /dev/sda5 (which are all mounted now) accesible to my apps? 

You see, not all apps can access these drives. Libre Office can. Android Studio and Floxbade can't. And I have no idea why. So my temporary fix is to use one of the 'Home' directories, and then after, move all the folders and files to my mounted drives, to save space. Again, please have patience with a newbie like me... :)

Comment: Nope... spoke too soon... after i successfully moved my HOME directory to the other NTFS drive, I lost the /dev/sda4 again. I counldn't mount it again @mikewhtever.

Comment: How do i post the screenshot?